# matlab find most similar rows in 2 matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, matching

I have 2 matrices

```
A = [66 1 29.2;
     80 0 29.4;
     80 0 29.4;
     79 1 25.6];

B = [66 1 28.2;
     79 0 28.4;
     66 1 27.6;
     80 0 22.4]
```

I would like to find the indeces of the matching rows.

```
indx = [1 1;
        2 4;
        3 2;
        4 3]
```

idx means that row1 of A matches with row1 of B, row2 of A with row4 of B etc.
It should be a pairwise matching (1 row of A with only 1 row of B)
For the values in column 2 it should be a strict match. For the values of columns 1 and 3 it should be the best match..(i.e. if it exist a pair with the same values good, otherwise we should pick the closest).

Can you help me? Tnx

**EDIT: MORE INSIGHTS ON THE QUESTION DERIVED FROM ANDREW'S COMMENT**

row 3 of A cant match row 4 B because row 4 B was already matched with row 2 of A. Row 2 of A matches row 4 of B because the first two elements 80,0 match and then there is a small error in the last element (29.4-22.4=7). 
We can say that matching properly the 2nd column of A and B is more important than matching the 1st column that is more important than matching the 3rd column. 
I

Comment: How come row 3 of `A` (identical to row 2) does not also match with row 4 of `B`?

Comment: it seems to me the match is calculated so you can't reuse rows. That answers Benoit_11 so row 3 cant match 4 because 4 was already matched. It also appears that the "distance" weights the elements left to right within a row. So row 2 of A matches row 4 because the first two elements `80,0` match and then there is a small error in the last element (29.4-22.4=7). Even though using a magnitude error, you see that row 2 of A is closest to row 2 of b (magnitude error is 2=> `sum(A(2,:)-B(2,:))`). In fact row B using a simple mag error is closest to A rows 2-4.

Comment: @gabboshow: Just copy pasting a comment won't help us understand. How can you derive more insights on your OWN question from someone else's comment? If you can't explain a rule for matching the rows with a sentence instead of an example there will be lots and lots of solutions to the question all giving different results on different data.

Comment: Don't post answers in the question. Post them as answers.

Comment: @knedlsepp thanks for your comment. The comment of Andrew helped me in understanding how to solve this problem and I posted a solution. I didn't really copied and pasted the comment, but took the useful parts and integrated. The rule is provided in the last part of the comment.

Comment: @knedlsepp did you delete my answer? could you please put it back so I can copy it into the answers?

Comment: Click on "edited 2 mins ago" you can see the revisions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2 : SOLUTION**

Thanks to the comments provided I managed to come up with a "not elegant" but working solution.

```
B_rem = B;
weights_error = [2 4 1];
match = zeros(size(A,1),2);

for i = 1 : size(A,1)
    score = zeros(size(B_rem,1),1);
    for j =1 : size(B_rem,1)
        score(j) = sum(abs(A(i,:) - B_rem(j,:)).*weights_error);
    end
    [~,idxmin] = min(score);
    match(i,:) = [i,idxmin];
    B_rem(idxmin,:)=[1000 1000 1000];

end

indx = match;

table_match = zeros(size(A,1),7);
table_match(:,1:3) = A(match(:,1),:);
table_match(:,5:7) = B(match(:,2),:);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem leaves a lot to the imagination:

- What is the criterion that two rows are similar? (What *metric*?)
- Is it better if a few rows match perfect and a few match ok or if all rows match pretty well?

One way of solving it would be to compute the pairwise distances using `pdist2` and then compute a [*stable matching/marriage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) based on those distances. This prefers few perfect matches over lots of good matches. You could use an existing implementation of such a matching algorithm. *Hanan Kavitz* provides [one of those](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34014-stable-matching) on the File Exchange.

```
% Compute distances
D = pdist2(A, B, 'euclidean');
% Compute preference based on distance
[~,A2B] = sort(D,2); A2B = A2B(:,end:-1:1);
% Compute Matching
J = stableMatching(A2B,A2B.');
matches = [(1:size(A,1)).',J]
```

This is quite flexible, as you can change the metric of `pdist2` according to how you define *similarity*. There are quite a few metrics already implemented, but you could also provide one of your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution makes an error in matching rows3 of A with rows3 of B. Please refer to @andrew 's comment if I was not totally clear on the problem.

Comment: @gabboshow: Your question is not clear and you should clarify instead. I mentioned the problems in my answer. You didn't even answer Benoit_11 as for why row 3 of A matches row 2 instead of 4.