# how to sort multidimensional matrices along multiple columns

Tags: matlab

I have a tricky matrix manipulation issue that I could really use some help with.

I need to reorganize a series of 2d matrices so that they align most effectively across subjects. Each matrix has ~50 rows (which are the observations) and 13 columns (which designate the 'weight' of each observation on a series of 13 outcome measures). Based on the manner in which the data are created, there is no inherent meaning in the order of the rows, however I need to reorganize each matrix such that the rows contain meaning *between* subjects.

Specifically, I want to be able to reorder the matrices such that the specific pattern of weightings in a given row aligns with a similar pattern in the same row across a group of 20 subjects. To make matters worse, some subjects have missing rows, although all have between 45 and 50 rows.

As an example:

subject 1:

```
[ 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7;
0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3]
```

subject 2:

```
[ 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2;
0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
```

problem: row 1 in subject 1 aligns best with row 2 in subject 2 (and v.v.) and I would like to reorganize them as such [note: the real life problem is much more convoluted than this].

I apologize ahead of time for how idiosyncratic this issue is, but I really appreciate any help that anyone can give.

Mac

Comment: What if two rows in one subject *aligns* with one row in another subject?

Comment: That could definitely happen. I'd be more than happy for there to be some overlap, but for the correspondence to be the best possible match.

Comment: I did answer a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28887640/3139711
As this is a rather vague problem, you will have to experiment with the distance-function used. The stable matching that is produced in this answer means: The highest priority is (a possibly small number of) very good matches. If you want lots of pretty good matches, you want a different algorithm.